# Convert .rrd file to json in python

Tags: python, rrd, ganglia

Is there any python module available for converting the .rrd file to json format ?

Comment: Why don't you use Google and tell us what you find?

Comment: I googled and got a solution but that is not optimal ..am asking about a direct python module ..?

Comment: Got the solution, I used the method " rrdtool.fetch(args)" in the module rrdtool, for extracting the data from rrd file and json convertion part manually by appending extracted strings with keys.

Comment: @mrag:  Please enter that as an answer - preferably with more detail - not a comment, so it's more obvious for future searchers.

Comment: will share the code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the code I tried for generating json from rrd file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import rrdtool
import sys

def printMetric():

  args = ["/var/lib/ganglia/rrds/__SummaryInfo__/cpu_system.rrd", "AVERAGE"]
  rrdMetric = rrdtool.fetch(args)

  time = rrdMetric[0][0]
  step = rrdMetric[0][2]

  sys.stdout.write("  {\n    \"Key1\":\"" + rrdMetric[1][0] +\
                   "\",\n    \"Key2\":\"" + "abcd" +\
                   "\",\n    \"metric_name\":\"" + "cpu_system" + "\",\n")  

  firstDP = True
  sys.stdout.write("    \"datapoints\":[\n")
  for tuple in rrdMetric[2]:
    if tuple[0] is not None:
      if not firstDP:
        sys.stdout.write(",\n")
      firstDP = False
      sys.stdout.write("      [")
      sys.stdout.write(str(tuple[0]))
      sys.stdout.write(",")
      sys.stdout.write(str(time))
      sys.stdout.write("]")
    time = time + step
  sys.stdout.write("\n    ]\n  }")

printMetric()
```

Comment: Consider using python json library. using json.dump() will take care about encoding python data structure (i.e. list of dictionaries) into json format and sending result into the STDOUT (or file) stream.

Answer (score -1):

There won't be an inbuilt library module for it.