# Converter .rrd to json

Tags: json, rrd

I am working on a project where I have a database in .rrd need and converts it to json, so can create graphs with jqueryplot. I tried to use the following code in the documentation could not more, returns me the following error. start time: unparsable time: toe. Does anyone have any idea what can I do?

Comment: You can maybe convert to js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286169/convert-rrd-file-to-json-in-python

Comment: What is "the following code"?  Looks like there's a missing link or example in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was Googling for this, and found a [blog post](http://monkeyswithbuttons.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/json-from-rrd/) mentioning [rrdtool xport --json](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdxport.en.html#I__json), added in rrdtool 1.4.6.  Does it not do what you want?

Comment: Thank you! and following the solution that's right, I was missing RRD understand how it worked correctly